# String input to character array

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, string, array

I am in between of project where i am getting string like "hello world" via Bluetooth to arduino I want to list this string into individual character so that I can call any of the character when required, this is not working i am getting only zeros in serial monitor 
please suggest what i am doing wrong

```
char s;
int k[10];

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop () {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    s = Serial.read();
  }
  k[10] = s;
  for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    Serial.println(k[x]);
    delay(200);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code sample:

---

You check for `Serial.available()>0`, but then assume/grab only one character:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  s = Serial.read();
}
```

It is possible that the serial receive buffer has more than one byte waiting, but you only capture one.

---

```
k[10] = s;
```

You assign the captured character to the last element of the byte array, regardless of all else. This presents two main problems

1. A C-style string must be terminated with a null character (`'\0'`), and you have immediately put real data in the position that should contain the terminating byte.
2. There is no possible way that bytes 0-9 can ever have any data written to them by this code.

---

Your code assumes that the entire string exists in `k[]` every time through `loop()`. Instead, you should assume that it might take hundreds or thousands of times through `loop()` just to finish receiving your string. The input string should have some kind of end-of-string marker like a newline (`'\n'`) or carriage-return (`'\r'`) (or both) so that your program can look for that and know when the input is fully received.

Below is a simple program that receives a string. Note that it has a portion labeled for when to process the recieved data. That block of code is only entered once a newline and/or carriage return are received.

```
#DEFINE MAX_INPUT 90

char inputBuffer[MAX_INPUT+1]; // Handles up to 90 bytes in a c-style string, with a null character termination.

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200); // initialization
  inputBuffer[0] = '\0'; //Initialize string to emtpy.
  Serial.println("Begin:");
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available()>0)
  {
    char input = Serial.read();
    static int s_len; // static variables default to 0
    if (s_len>=MAX_INPUT) {
      // Have received already the maximum number of characters
      // Ignore all new input until line termination occurs
    } else if (input != '\n' && input != '\r') {
      inputBuffer[s_len++] = input;
    } else {
      // Have received a LF or CR character

      // INSERT YOUR CODE HERE TO PROCESS THE RECEIVED DATA //
      // YOU COULD COPY TO A NEW VARIABLE WITH strncpy() OR //
      // SET A FLAG TO SAY TO START SOME OTHER TASK         //
      Serial.print("RECEIVED MSG: ");
      Serial.println(inputBuffer);

      memset(inputBuffer, 0, sizeof(inputBuffer));
      s_len = 0;             // Reset input buffer here if you
                             // have already copied the data.
                             // If you don't reset here, then
                             // you can't start receiving more
                             // serial port data. This is your
                             // 'software' serial buffer, contrast
                             // with the hardware serial buffer.
    }
  }
}
```